# Is EnumWindows thread safe

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a very basic question :
is `EnumWindows` thread safe ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? Will it [not] get you into trouble if new windows appear while you enumerate? I doubt so, otherwise no one would ever use it, as it is supposed to enumerate windows from other processes.

Comment: I just want to know if I can use this function in a Thread.

Comment: Everything happens in a thread.

Comment: Yes you can. How can you use a function *not* in a thread? Do you mean *not in the main thread of your app*? Yes, you can, because windows that belong to other processes do not care which thread of yours is main.

Comment: Yes. Not in the main thread. That was my question.

Comment: If you are concerned about the comment "EnumWindows is omitting windows" to the MSDN article at the link above - do not worry: just  commentator ElmueSoft does not know about messages-only windows.

Answer (score 3):

You can call `EnumWindows` safely from any thread. As a general rule, Windows API functions are thread safe. Exceptions to this general rule will be sign posted in a function's documentation.

Answer (score 3):

> Not in the main thread. That was my question

Some functions from user32.dll are thread-sensitive, you can dig yourself a pretty deep hole if you call, say, SendMessage() for a custom message on a worker thread.  But no, EnumWindows() has no such problem, it doesn't care whether the thread is pumping a message loop and does not rely on thread state.  You do of course need to account for the possibility that the window handle you get in the callback might be for a window that was destroyed just a fraction of a second earlier, EnumWindows() does *not* freeze every thread of every process that created a window.